# returning ArrayList to String

Tags: java, string, arraylist, return

I've manage to put ArrayList values into a String, when I printout the String in the console, everything works fine, it gets all the info, but when I return the String, it only displays the last element.

e.g.
There are 3 garages in the String

```
BMW Garages
Mercedes Garages
Toyta Garages
```

When I return it, it displays only the last one:

```
Toyta Garages
```

Here is the code that I am working with:

```
private String arrayListToString()
{
    NepGarazasCtr garCtr = new NepGarazasCtr();
    ArrayList<NepGarazas> gautGar = garCtr.gautVisusGarazus();

    String nepGar = "";

    for(NepGarazas npGar: gautGar)
    {
        nepGar = npGar.getGarazoPav();
        System.out.println(nepGar);
        //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nepGar));
    }
    return nepGar;
}
```

And this is where I put it:

```
String[] array = { arrayListToString() };
```

**So my question would be:** How to return the whole String, not just the last element? Or it is not possible? I want to put the String in the JComboBox.

Thank you.

Comment: Try more simplified variable names in english that users can understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the problem is that you are trying to return a single String, instead of an actual array of the Strings. Therefore, what you should do is actually create an array, and return that to the String[] variable, rather than just a single attribute. Your solution could work in C# using yield return in the foreach, but not in this scenario. Therefore, here is a simple solution to the problem, albeit not the best one (I created a new list rather than create an array the size of gautGar's size, I'll append that to the end):

```
private String[] arrayListToString()
{
    NepGarazasCtr garCtr = new NepGarazasCtr();
    List<NepGarazas> gautGar = garCtr.gautVisusGarazus();

    List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(NepGarazas npGar: gautGar)
    {
        stringList.add(npGar.getGarazoPav());
        System.out.println(nepGar);
        //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nepGar));
    }
    return stringList.toArray(new String[stringList.size()]);
}


...


String[] array =  arrayListToString();
```

Or just do

```
private String[] arrayListToString()
{
    NepGarazasCtr garCtr = new NepGarazasCtr();
    List<NepGarazas> gautGar = garCtr.gautVisusGarazus();

    String[] stringArray = new String[gautGar.size()];

    for(int i = 0; i < gautGar.size(); i++)
    {
        NepGarazas npGar = gautGar.get(i);
        stringArray[i] = npGar.getGarazoPav();
        System.out.println(nepGar);
    }
    return stringArray;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to set some `String` in a `JComboBox`. Well, you can simply use a `DefaultComboBoxModel<String>`.
*Note:* This below code use the diamond operator `<>` from Java 7, you should change this if you use and older java version.

```
String[] stringArray = arrayListToString() ;
DefaultComboBoxModel<String> comboBoxModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(stringArray);
JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<>(comboBoxModel);
```

As you can see, you just have to initialize `stringArray` using your method.
So, **the main error in your code is the return type of `arrayListToString()`**, which may be `String[]` and not `String`.

```
private String[] arrayListToString() {
  //Look at the Zhuinden's answer ;)
}
```

You propably should change the method's name too, something like `arrayListToStringArray()` should be more appropriate now :)

Answer (score 0):

You said it printed the array just fine, so `System.out.println(nepGar);` works as you want it. I think your only problem is that each loop, you are setting the entire string `nepGar` to the current element, meaning on the last iteration, the string will be the value of the last element.

Instead of setting that string to be the element each time, *append* each element, meaning the last element will still be part of string, but you're just *adding* to it. I think you just want to change this line:

```
nepGar = npGar.getGarazoPav();
```

to this:

```
nepGar += npGar.getGarazoPav() + "\n";
```

Comment: While I thought about this (albeit I would have also made him use a StringBuffer), I think if he needs it for a JComboBox, then they'll be seperate elements only if they're each a seperate String in the String[], rather than a single blob with newlines.

Comment: @Zhuinden StringBuffer is completely unnecessary when answering questions like these. They just confuse people. But yes you're right in what he probably needs instead, however I just answered the question he specifically asked for returning the string.

Comment: I'd rather show them the *right* practice so they don't commit silly mistakes later, as per http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/java/strings.html

Comment: += with Strings in a loop is a very bad practice and a huge performance killer! I'd refrain from recommending this practice!

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd Huge performance killer? He's looping through an ArrayList with three elements. Seriously, in simple cases like this, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Zhuinden if you used a StringBuffer, it would confuse the OP and daunt him into not even reading your answer. It's not the point of the question. He can learn about immutable strings and string concatenation another time. Maybe put a footnote about it at the bottom. But the real question is about algorithmic design, not showing him the correct practice with every little thing. It's just not that big of a deal, especially in this case. It takes away from the clarity of your answer for no good reason.